# Best way to write this logic comparing three variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still new and flummoxed by this logic.. Maybe I need more coffee.. But here goes.

I have three values color, size and material. And I need to assign them to the array "options".

These variables have either a value or are assigned "nil". So the following will return a true or false for each:

```
color.nil?
size.nil?
material.nil?
```

If color AND size are nil then I want the value of material assigned to options. Which is straight forward:

```
if color.nil? && size.nil?
  options = material
end
```

However the trouble I have is if color or size are NOT nil then I want to assign one or both of those to the options array and not use the material variable at all.

What's the simplest way to do that?

Comment: what is **options**, an array or a hash?

Comment: And how would you use that hash?

Comment: `options = {}` to initialise the hash, then `options[:material] = material` to set the material key to your material object, then you can access it with `options[:material]` which may or may not return nil depending on what you set it to in the previous step. Replace `material` with `color` and `size` and you have an `options` hash with all your values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle your specific use-case scenario but to just answer your question, you could do it like this:

```
if color.nil? && size.nil?
  options = material
else
  options = [color, size].reject(&:nil?)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

with this code:

```
[color, size, material].compact.first
```

you are saying, return the first which is not null. So, if color is null but size has a value of 4 and material has a value of 9, the expression will return 4. If color and size are null, then, you will get whatever value is material(in case it has a value). If all values are null, you will get null.

or another way:

```
options = color || size || material
```

Comment: Except there's no `null` in ruby :)

Comment: yeah, you're right :D. btw, I still believe the second option I put looks better than the accepted answer :-)

Comment: It looks better, but it's incorrect. If both color and size are non-nil, your code will choose only color. But `[color, size]` is needed.

Comment: ok, I think I misunderstood the requirements. The requirements say: "I want to assign one or both of those..". So, I thought one of them was enough.